# Share a custom made Visual Studio 2010 toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've created a new Toolbar in Visual Studio 2010 and added some custom buttons to it (mainly utilising the External commands).

I'd now like to share that toolbar with others, or be able to "save" it so that I could re-import at a later date.

I know that you can use the Import and Export Settings Wizard to back-up all your settings and re-import them elsewhere, but it does not allow you to Export a single toolbar instance.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I might be able to do this?  I don't mind if it's just a settings file I have to save, a VS Extension I have to write, or an installer package I have to create - I'd just like to be able to share my toolbar!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working in 2008, but in the Import Export Settings Wizard, limiting it to 
General Settings > Menu and Command Bar Customizations
will narrow it down to just your toolbars.

The settings file is all just XML so you can look at stripping out your personal preferences and leaving just the elements of your custom toolbar.